# Is this the right way to view an SQL prepared statement?

Tags: sql

I'm trying looking for confirmation to see if the way that I understand SQL prepared statements is correct.

If I'm understanding it right,it's that you are separating the input of the user, from the statement itself. You are not treating the input as part of the statement, or under the same *context*. In the case of SQL injection, the context is a string. The statement is one long string, and you are allowing the user to put whatever they want as input, and that input is then part of the statement.

So instead, put some parameter name in its place, save the SQL statement somewhere to be used for later. The parameter is not a string, but some "object" that points to data. Then if you want to pass something like `'' or '1' ='1'`, then the parameter points to this value as a *string*. So if you compare the two:

*input gets appended to the statement*

`delete from t where 'hello'='' or '1' = '1';` `// will delete`t``

*input gets pointed to by some parameter in the statement*

1. Create the statement. This gets stored somewhere as a statement, not a string.

`delete* from t where password=$somepassword;`

When `where password=$somepassword` evaluates, $somepassword is replaced by the string it's pointing to. Then we have this statement:

`delete * from t where password='' or '1'='1';` // it does not pass, because everything besides the string is a statement. The string is not part of the statement itself. Since any string is not treated as part of the statement, then no SQL injection can occur.

Comment: This sounds pretty close to correct. One correction/quibble: *"save the SQL statement somewhere to be used for later."*. What happens is this statement is sent to the database and fully compiled. The parsing, and optimization is complete and the execution path is fully realized. Then you pass in parameters that are executed in that precompiled execution path. There is no chance to change the execution path via user input/injection because it's already determined. That's what makes it superior to other techniques  of avoiding sql injection like cleansing/sanitization.

Comment: So if I'm understanding, when you do not use prepared statement, it means that you are able to compile part of the input also? The compiler reads the statement as since the input is part of it, then parts of the input can be parsed as some statement. Then if you use a prepared statement, the compiling is already done. When you pass some string into the parameter, you are passing the "uncompiled" version of the string, so in other words it's just a literal string

Comment: That's exactly right. SQL is just a string that is passed to the database. It compiles it. When you pass a sql statement as a prepared statement into the database it compiles it and awaits the parameters. Those parameters are treated as literals (string, numeric, date, or otherwise) and can't change the predetermined/compiled execution path for that statement. It's really a two step process. 1) compile the statement 2) send in parameters. Most databases allow you to continue to use the compiled prepared statements many times where you can change out the parameters and get different result sets

Comment: @JNevill Interesting. Thanks for your help.